# Perl join and split operation

Tags: perl, join, split

I tried a small test :
to replace `x` in `x|y|z|a` with `w`
so i tried:

```
echo "x|y|z|a" | perl -lne '@arr=split /|/;$arr[0]='w';$_=join "|",@arr;print $_;'
```

it gave me:

```
> echo "x|y|z|a" | perl -lne '@arr=split /|/;$arr[0]='w';$_=join "|",@arr;print $_;'
w|||y|||z|||a
>
```

surprisingly it gave 3 field separators instead of one.
can anybody tell me where am i wrong?

Comment: `'w'` should probably be `"w"`

Comment: Should we assume you're *not* looking for answers like `tr///`, `s///`, an lvalue-able `substr($_, 0, 1)`, and so on ? ;-)

Comment: No  i am not lokking for them !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regular expression is an alternation between two empty patterns. You can use `/\|/` to match a literal `|` instead.

Comment: Specifically, `|` is a special character that means "or", so `/|/` means "Match on an empty string or an empty string".  That will match every time.